# How do I solve error: Tensor object has not atrribute 'fold'

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision

I have a method that divides an image into patches and change the colour of a specified patch. I tried merging the patches together  after the manipulation and I got the error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'fold'`

```
def perturb_patch(img, patch_idx, patch_size, stride):
    img = img.unsqueeze(0)
    patches = img.unfold(2, patch_size, stride).unfold(3, patch_size, stride)
    patches = patches.reshape(1, 3, -1, patch_size, patch_size)
    patches = patches.squeeze(0).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
    patches[patch_idx][0, :, :] = 0.09803922
    patches[patch_idx][1,:, :] = 0.21333333
    patches[patch_idx][2,:, :] = 0.61176471

    merged_patches = patches.fold(img.shape[-2:], kernel_size=16, stride=16, padding=0)
    return merged_patches
```

When I tried returning `patches` instead of `merged_patches` with  `new_img = perturb_patch(img, 6, 16, 16)`, I could visualize the patches and the manipulated patch was noticeable. How do I merge this patches together to form the original image which of size `(3, 224, 224)`?

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to find an alternative to merge the patches together with the pytorch's [view](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) method [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fold-patches-of-images-back-to-single-image/61395/3?u=binbbaz).

updated code:

```
def perturb_patch(img, patch_idx, patch_size, stride):

    img = img.unsqueeze(0)
    patches = img.unfold(2, patch_size, stride).unfold(3, patch_size, stride)
    patches = patches.reshape(1, 3, -1, patch_size, patch_size)
    patches = patches.squeeze(0).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)

    patches[patch_idx][0, :, :] = 0.09803922
    patches[patch_idx][1,:, :] = 0.21333333
    patches[patch_idx][2,:, :] = 0.61176471

    unsqueezed_patch = patches.unsqueeze(0)
    grid_size = (14, 14)
    batch_size, num_patches, c, height, width = unsqueezed_patch.size()
    image = unsqueezed_patch.view(batch_size, grid_size[0], grid_size[1], c, height, width)
    output_height = grid_size[0] * height
    output_width = grid_size[1] * width

    image = image.permute(0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5).contiguous()
    image = image.view(batch_size, c, output_height, output_width)

    return image
```